# QMessageBox you can select text from

Tags: qt

Is there any way to display a `QMessageBox` that would have selectable text, so that user would be able to use their mouse or keyboard to select and copy its contents somehow? I know I can create labels that do it, but not sure about the Message Boxes. Standard message box in MS Windows definitely doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: What about `QMessageBox`'s `setTextInteractionFlags` and set it to `Qt::TextSelectableByMouse`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer to solve this using style sheet.
Run this once and this will impact all message boxes created anywhere in application:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QMessageBox { messagebox-text-interaction-flags: 5; }");
```

I've test this with Qt 5.5 for OS X, and it works.

Comment: Does it append to existing style sheet or completely overwrite it? I am not sure if someone else didn't already use similar code somewhere in that project.

Comment: it overrides existing stylesheets applied on `QApplication`. If you are using style sheets already then simply add this entry to your file.

Answer (score 16):

You need to enable the `TextSelectableByMouse` interaction flag:

```
QMessageBox mb(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "New message",
               "A lot of text", QMessageBox::Ok, this);
mb.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
int dialogResult = mb.exec();
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with Qt4. ***error C2039: 'setTextInteractionFlags' : is not a member of 'QMessageBox'***

Comment: I see that was added in Qt-5.1. I had to use the stylesheet since I can not use Qt5 in the application that I am working on because of a complicated library dependency.